# List all aliases starting with a particular string

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

To improve on the steps I have to take to complete some actions on my Mac, I have created many aliases. Example:

1. To open System Preferences, which I have to do often to manage multiple monitors, I have created the following alias in `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   alias pref='open -a System\ Preferences'
   ```
2. To put my setup in "Work From Home" mode, I have:

   ```
   alias wfh='code&rdc&smc&'
   ```

   which opens Visual Studio Code, the Remote Desktop and the Cisco Mobility Client.
3. To work with aliases themselves I have:

   ```
   alias editbash='nano ~/.bash_profile;source ~/.bash_profile'
   ```

   which opens the `~/.bash_profile` in nano editor and then when I'm done, it automatically sources the updated contents of the file for me.

---

**Question:**

I have numerous aliases that are all related to git. I often forget the alias for some actions. However, the good news is that all of my git aliases start with `gt`.

How can I list only the aliases that start with a particular string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**grep** for them

---

1. Far better suggestion from the comments - **grep on alias.**

   You can list all your aliases, even the ones not written in `~/.bash_profile`, by calling `alias`.

   grep the result to find the aliases starting from `gt` as:

   ```
   alias | grep "^alias gt"
   ```

---

2. Since the aliases are created by writing `alias <alias_name>=...`, to list the aliases starting with, for example, `gt`, you can do:

   ```
   grep "^alias gt" ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   The `^` in the grep argument is an anchor. The caret `^` and the dollar sign `$` are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.

   In `^alias gt`, it implies that you want only those lines that start with "alias gt". On my machine, I get the following result:

   ```
   alias gts="git status" 
   alias gtd="git diff" 
   alias gtpull="git pull"
   alias gtb="git branch"  
   alias gtpush="git push"  
   alias gtpullmk="gtpull;./make all"  
   alias gtst="git stash"  
   alias gtstash="gtst save"  
   alias gtstlist="gtst list"  
   alias gtctall="runformatter;git commit -a"
   ```

---

3. Alternatively, you could grep without the anchor as:

   ```
   grep gt ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   Here, you are simply looking for any line that contains the substring "gt", anywhere. As a result, you may get some unnecessary lines, but you will get all aliases that use any of your git aliases.

   On my machine, I get the following output using this search. Notice the extra line at the top, which was not present in the previous output:

   ```
   alias debugmk="echows;gtb;${ws}/make ${DEBUG_OPTIONS}"  
   alias gts="git status"  
   alias gtd="git diff"  
   alias gtpull="git pull"  
   alias gtb="git branch"  
   alias gtpush="git push"  
   alias gtpullmk="gtpull;./make all"  
   alias gtst="git stash"  
   alias gtstash="gtst save"  
   alias gtstlist="gtst list"  
   alias gtctall="runformatter;git commit -a"
   ```

---

4. Finally, depending upon which command you find more useful (or even go for both if they both are useful), you can create a new alias to list all git related aliases:

   ```
   alias allgit="alias | grep gt"
   ```

Comment: Whoa...overly complex!  How about just doing `alias | grep "^alias gt"` instead of processing your bash profile.  This will cover all aliases, even the ones *not* set in `.bash_profile`

Comment: @Allan: Didn't know. Much better.

Comment: Also you don't need to `cat` into `grep` :-)

Comment: @nohillside: Didn't know that either. TY for updating the answer.

Comment: @nohillside: Maybe I should mark this answer Community Wiki now. :D

Comment: It's still your answer, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Programmable Completion Builtins `compgen` command with the `a` option. The syntax looks like:

```
compgen [option] [word]
```

The `a` option lists all the `aliases` and `word` matches all the aliases beginning with those characters. So, to answer your question to list all git aliases:

```
compgen -a gt
```

More info can be found with this command:

```
help compgen
```

Comment: `compgen` is not builtin. Doing `man compgen` says "No manual entry for compgen".

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html